# MYSQL query a billion records and timeout issues

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MYSQL Database with one table that is growing by 5,000 rows a second. I expect this table to get into the Billions of records. I have a query function in php right now:

```
 $result =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  `data`='".$input."' LIMIT 0 , 30");
```

The problem is obvious the bigger the table gets the longer it takes to query the latest records. To the point, where the function just times out. If I run the same query from sql directly it does the same thing.

Is there a better way to query this table to speed up query times. Is it possible to query starting from the last record, first record and incrementally in between to speed this up?

Also I am not dead set in using php if there is a faster alternative please let me know.

Also would it be better to split the table into multiple tables and run the query at the same time on multiple smaller tables?

Comment: Do you have an index?  Your query has no `ORDER BY` clause, so MySQL will make a guess on how to sort records, and may well make the _wrong_ guess.  Add an `ORDER BY` on an indexed column - without one the order isn't deterministic anyway.

Comment: I'll also add that `SELECT *` almost never belongs in production code. Though it shouldn't slow the query, it may have an effect on what column MySQL choose to sort on. Always be explicit about the columns you actually need.

Comment: You could try indexing on the `data` column, but that would slow down your updates by having to update the index on every INSERT. You could perhaps alleviate that problem by using `INSERT DELAYED`, or alternatively buffering your input and adding large blocks of updates with a single `INSERT` statement.

Comment: at some point disk access times are going to be an issue as well. if i ever got to such a situation i would be looking for professional external help :-) sharding, Horizontal partitioning, all sorts of things you need to know about at this level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes are very important here. Makes huge difference. Also make sure it is normalized correctly.

Another, more hands on idea, is to not have one big db. But separate it into many smaller, based on a criteria that you know when querying it later. Like, date, first letter, etc. It is not practical to have this big db growing all the time. It has to be divided.

Another division could be to store older data in slower bigger chunks. Saving newer used data in temp tables.

Comment: rather simplistic, there are 'methods' to handling big data

Comment: Yep. Just some crude advice. There are a lot more to say on the subject, naturally... If it is a big project that needs to handle big loads initially, best methods should be investigated first. But that might be at another "level" of development.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a big table and the values you are interested in are "latest" the you could improve performance using MySQL [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html). More you can check this [article](http://www.chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows).

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are one part of the story here..

Try to avoid LIMIT with a start and end. 
if you use LIMIT 1000000, 30 the mysql server needs to keep 1000030 records in memory so it's very resource wasting to throw away 1000000 records again to keep 30, especially when mysql should make a temp table on disk this wil happen when the memory table becomes to large...